# Sodium bicarbonate to sodium carbonate decomposition

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, boiling-point, decomposition

Recently I ran the reaction:

$$\ce{2NaHCO3 ->[400°C] Na2CO3 + H2O + CO2}$$

I wanted an explanation why the sodium bicarbonate ($\ce{NaHCO3}$) decomposed into sodium carbonate ($\ce{Na2CO3}$), water ($\ce{H2O}$), and carbon dioxide ($\ce{CO2}$); and didn’t just turn to sodium bicarbonate in its gas form, since its boiling point is 333.6 °C.

Comment: You would not be considered less educated if you called H2O just water. Nobody calls it dihydrogen monoxide. BTW, names of compounds are not capitalized. // [NaHCO3](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sodium_bicarbonate) starts to decompose at 50 °C before even melting. // Remember NaHCO3 is also called "baking soda" and it would not be used for baking if food would be carbonized first.

Comment: Sodium bicarbonate does not have a gas form at all.

Comment: So there are some compounds with only one state of matter?

Comment: I guess most of compounds decompose before melting. Simple inorganic or organic compounds able to be melted without damage are rather exceptions. // There is no bicarbonate in other than solid phase and for most of cations not even as solid // Have you even witnessed burnt food? Food is notorious for refusing to be melted or evaporated and then frozen and condensed. It prefers being decomposed, finally to some carbonized mess.

Comment: So that’s why is sodium carbonate?

Comment: The question is unclear. Sodium carbonate is stable enough to melt at 851 deg C, regardless of how stable or not is sodium bicarbonate.

Comment: One of the [suppliers](https://www.alfa-chemistry.com/product/sodium-bicarbonate-cas-144-55-8-290277.html) claims the boiling point is 851 degC but does say it decomposes at much lower temperature. I wonder where this claim comes from (it is pervasive).

Comment: Technical note: If you want a user, that is not the author of the commented question or answer, to be notified about a new comment, start the comment by @username. Otherwise, he may miss the comment.

Comment: @MatteoZervos  why did this happen? Because it is energetically favourable.

Comment: Does this mean it’s nucleus is excited or is this totally a different subject?

Comment: Even though it’s a bit dictatorial, thank you for editing my posts and composition them more correctly. I was on an iPad and didn’t know how to write “chemistry numbers”— the ones that are smaller and lowered down.

Answer (score 3):

> I wanted an explanation to the reason that the sodium bicarbonate ($\ce{NaHCO3}$) decomposed into sodium carbonate ($\ce{Na2CO3}$), water ($\ce{H2O}$), and carbon dioxide ($\ce{CO2}$); and didn’t just turn to sodium bicarbonate in its gas form, since its boiling point is $\pu{333.6 ^\circ C}$.

You wouldn't have this question if you have spent some time to find out some scientific evidence of when and how $\ce{NaHCO3}$ starts to decompose instead of putting certain temperature, $\pu{400 ^\circ C}$, as the decomposition temperature. As Poutnik cleverly pointed out that in his comment, $\ce{NaHCO3}$ starts to decompose temperatures as low as $\pu{100 ^\circ F}$ (about $\pu{38 ^\circ C}$; Ref.1), thus, the temperature is even not closed to the boiling point of $\ce{NaHCO3}$ before its structure starts to change. Of course, the temperature at which decomposition occurs will depend on the extent of back pressures of the carbon dioxide and water vapors and particle size of the $\ce{NaHCO3}$ granules as well (Ref.1):

[image: Rate of CO2 evolution]
[image: Temperature on particle size-1]
[image: Temperature on particle size-2]

To be clear, the above figures (from Ref.1) are showing the sodium bicarbonate  thermal  decomposition data, fractional  conversion as a function of time, $t$, for three particle size ranges and six temperatures in the range $225$-$\pu{350 ^\circ F}$ ($107$-$\pu{177 ^\circ C}$), the temperatures of which are much lower than $\pu{333.6 ^\circ C}$!

The following conclusions are made based on Ref.1 experimental data:

1. The thermal decomposition of $\ce{NaHCO3}$, granules is chemical kinetically controlled in the temperature range of $225$-$\pu{350 ^\circ F}$ ($380$-$\pu{450 K}$). The shrinking  core  model provides a good fit to the data.
2. The rate coefficient, $k$, is of Arrhenius form,  with an activation energy of $\pu{20.5 kcal/mol}$ $(\pu{85.8 kJ/mol})$.
3. The decomposition rate of $\ce{NaHCO3}$, in the temperature range of $\pu{150 ^\circ C}$ ($\pu{302 ^\circ F}$) is not affected by $\ce{CO2}$ partial pressures as high as about $\pu{0.01 atm}$.

The authors have also provided an equation for the estimated decomposition times, $\tau$ in conclusion, which is not relevant here.

The following year of this work, another group has published extended work on the thermal decomposition of solid $\ce{NaHCO3}$ in the temperature range of $360$-$\pu{500 K}$ showing first order kinetic on decomposition at lower temperatures $(\lt \pu{440 K})$ in nitrogen atmosphere (Ref.2). According to the result, the mechanism for the decomposition process, which is essentially that of rearrangement of bicarbonate ions, is given as:

$$\ce{HCO3- ->[\Delta] OH- + CO2} \tag1$$
$$\ce{OH- + HCO3- ->CO3^2- +H2O} \tag2$$

The authors stated that:

> Proton transfer, as indicated in reaction (2), will be facile in this case because of the chains of hydrogen-bonded bicarbonate ions present in the crystal structure; these can easily be visualized as reacting in pairs. Since the growth stage is unaffected by carbon dioxide or water vapor, it is likely that both reactions are essentially irreversible.

---

**References:**

1. Timothy C. Keener, George C. Frazier, and Wayne C. Davis, "Thermal Decomposition of Sodium Bicarbonate," *Chemical Engineering Communications* **1985**, *33(1-4)*, 93-105 (ODI: https://doi.org/10.1080/00986448508911162).
2. Matthew C. Ball, Christine M. Snelling, Alec N. Strachan, and Rebecca M. Strachan, "Thermal Decomposition of Solid Sodium Bicarbonate," *Journal of the Chemical Society, Faraday Transactions 1: Physical Chemistry in Condensed Phases* **1986**, *82(12)*, 3709-3715 (ODI: https://doi.org/10.1039/F19868203709).

Comment: O.K. Thank you for your answer. I also wanted to ask where you find all this information because it’s nowhere in surface Google.

Comment: Good question, Matteo ! How did Mathew Mahindaratne manage to find this reference ?

Comment: @Maurice: As in my profile, I teach at Texas A&M University, which has one of the best libraries in the country.

Comment: Also, been a member of ReserchGate help as well.

Comment: Thank you. I don’t have access to many other chemistry sources since pretty much I’m not learning any of these in school yet. I’ve been trying alone and I think I’ve been pretty good so far for 12. I’ll definitely view ReasearchGate and if im lucky some Texas A&M online documents!